# jq: How to create output in a tabular format from a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, header, jq, tabular

I have JSON as given below.

```json
[
   {
      "users": [
         {
            "name": "alfred",
            "points": 10
         },
         {
            "name": "alice",
            "points": 11
         },
         {
            "name": "emma",
            "points": 33
         }
      ],
      "house": "red"
   },
   {
      "users": [
         {
            "name": "Logan",
            "points": 20
         },
         {
            "name": "Keith",
            "points": 19
         },
         {
            "name": "Lisa",
            "points": 18
         },
         {
            "name": "Julia",
            "points": 45
         }
      ],
      "house": "blue"
   }
]
```

How do I create a tabular output as follows? Basically, I need the value of house appear in the corresponding rows.

The desired output table

```
|Name  |  Points|House|
|alfred|    10  |red  |
|alice |    11  |red  |
|emma  |    33  |red  |
|Logan |    20  |blue |
|Keith |    19  |blue |
|Lisa  |    18  |blue |
|Julia |    45  |blue |
```

This is what I tried.

```bash
% jq '.[]|.users[]| .name' test.json

"alfred"
"alice"
"emma"
"Logan"
"Keith"
"Lisa"
"Julia"

% jq '.[]|.users[]| (.name, .points)' test.json

"alfred"
10
"alice"
11
"emma"
33
"Logan"
20
"Keith"
19
"Lisa"
18
"Julia"
45
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's OK to forego some formatting and decorations, this produces a simple table.

```bash
$ jq -r '["Name", "Points", "House"],(.[]|.house as $house|.users[]|[.name, .points, $house])|@tsv' test.json
Name    Points  House
alfred  10  red
alice   11  red
emma    33  red
Logan   20  blue
Keith   19  blue
Lisa    18  blue
Julia   45  blue
```

Getting rid of the variable assignment, this outputs the same simple table.

```bash
$ jq -r '["Name", "Points", "House"],(.[]|(.users[]|[.name, .points]) + [.house])|@tsv' test.json
```

Answer (score 3):

With your input, the following jq program produces the output shown below:

```
jq -r '
  def lpad($len): tostring | ($len - length) as $l | (" " * $l)[:$l] + .;
  (["Names","Points", "House"]
   | ., map(length*"_")),
  (.[] | (.users[] | [.name, .points]) +  [.house]) 
  | map(lpad(8)) | join("|")'
```

```
   Names|  Points|   House
   _____|  ______|   _____
  alfred|      10|     red
   alice|      11|     red
    emma|      33|     red
   Logan|      20|    blue
   Keith|      19|    blue
    Lisa|      18|    blue
   Julia|      45|    blue
```

For a tiny bit more generality at the expense of a tiny bit of complexity:

```
  def lpad($len): tostring | ($len - length) as $l | (" " * $l)[:$l] + .;
  def max(s): reduce s as $x (-infinite; if $x > . then $x else . end);
    max("House",  .[].house|length) as $hl
  | max("Points", .[].users[].points|tostring|length) as $pl
  | max("Names",  .[].users[].name|length) as $nl
  | [ ("Names" | lpad($nl)), ("Points" | lpad($pl)), ("House"| lpad($hl))],
    [$nl * "_", $pl * "_", $hl * "_"],
    (.[] | ((.users[] | [(.name | lpad($nl)), (.points|lpad($pl))]) +  [.house | lpad($hl)] ))
  | join("|")
```

Season to taste.